# "Ich sehe fern" vs "Ich schaue fern"

Tags: word-usage, verb-usage, separable-verb

What is the difference between the following?:

> - Ich sehe fern.
> - Ich schaue fern.

Also, can we formulate the following sentence with *sehen* instead?

> Ich schaue Fußball nur im Fernsehen.

Comment: I watchvBetween two ferns. Does that count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Schauen* is Southern German. People in the north understand it but don't use it actively. The Northern/Central German expression is *gucken* (the initial *g* is spoken as *k*), it's not too common in the south.

*Ansehen*, *angucken* and *anschauen* are better alternatives for your example sentence:

> Ich schaue (mir) Fußball nur im Fernsehen **an**.
>
> Ich gucke (mir) Fußball nur im Fernsehen **an**.
>
> Ich sehe (mir) Fußball nur im Fernsehen **an**.

The verb *fernsehen* does not have an accusative object, so it's no alternative for your example sentence.

Comment: For me "gucken" is also used often in southern germany. But this verb is only used in colloquial speech.

Comment: Dunno. I don't know anyone who would say "Ich gucke/schaue/sehe Fußball im Fernsehen **an**". Not one single person. And "sich etwas anschauen/ansehen" has the connotation of "taking a closer look", not just "watching"

Comment: @IQV: Perhaps *»gucken«* is used in southern Germany, but not in the south of the German-speaking area, which also includes Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Austria and Italy (South Tyrol). In the German-speaking countries south of Germany, only immigrants and tourists from Germany use *»gucken«.*

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: *»Ich schaue mir einen Film im Fernsehen **an**.«* is perfectly correct German that is used at least where I live (Austria). This sounds terribly wrong to me: *»Ich schaue mir einen Film im Fernsehen.«* (same with *»sehe«/»gucke«* instead of *»schaue«*). It becomes a little bit better if you omit *»mir«* (*»Ich schaue einen Film im Fernsehen.«*), and I know people who actively use this construction, but to me it still sounds very strange.

Answer (score -2):

Es handelt sich offensichtlich um ein Missverständnis.

*Fernsehen* ist erstmal prinzipiel richtig, meine Meinung.

*Schauen* is dialektalisch, aber warum?

1. VergleichE engl. *show*. Offensichtlich besteht eine wechselseitige Beziehung zwischen zeigen und wahrnehmen. Die Ableitungsverhältnisse sind ungewiss. Beweise zum Gegenteil bitte in die Kommentare.
2. Oblique Subjekte, bspw. *Mir ist kalt*, sind ausweislich einschlägiger Fachliteratur ein fester Bestandteil indogermanischer Grammatik, doch dürften die Details wiederum unklar sein.
3. Bairisch kennt *mir* "ich; wir" als reguläres Subjekt.

Auf dieser Grundlage scheint mir die Vermutung anschaulich und auch wahrscheinlich, ***mir schaun*** hätte gehießen "mir wird gezeigt" und ebenso "ich sehe".

---

Der Unterschied ist bei oberflächlicher Betrachtung nicht zu erkennen. Immerhin ist *Schaun mer mal* definitiv bayerisch und könnte heißen "wir werden sehen" oder genauso gut "es wird sich zeigen" (notabene *sich* als reflexives Pronomen kommt ohne *uns* aus).

Bei dem letzteren ist fraglich, ob *(si)ch* < **sek* mit **se* und einer ungeklärten Partikel **Ge* zum Suffix *ge-* zu rechnen ist oder doch wie üblich angenommen zu **Kom*; tut hier aber nicht viel zur Sache, daher ist die relative Chronologie erstmal unerheblich.

Aus pragmatischer Sicht, da grammatische Ableitungsverhältnisse in Ablaut und Ableitungen bei synchroner Betrachtung jedenfalls nicht erkennbar sind, ist eine Überschneidung der beiden Verben nicht zu verkennen.

In Diachronie ist zu bemängeln, *soll* neben *Schuld* und *Schultheiß* zeigt eine vereinzelte Deaffrikazion (s. Affrizierung **sk* > *sch*, vgl. engl. *should* "sollte"), die ebensogut für *schauen* und *sehen* vermutet werden könnte. Weiteres ungewiss.